# nginx should not forward request to fastcgi server when it is overloaded

Tags: performance, nginx, fastcgi, php

Say I have nginx-balancer and some php-fastcgi servers.
It happens that one of servers is crashed down or is overloaded, so it can't process request.
Is there any way to prevent nginx delegate requests to that server?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you should check upstream health checks, not sure if it's available only in the plus version or in the free one too.

Comment: As soon as nginx learns that upstream server is not responding nginx will not send request to that server. There [health_check](http://nginx.org/r/health_check), but only in commercial version of nginx.